# Ubuntu won't detect Btrek H9 bluetooth headset anymore

Tags: sound, 15.04, bluetooth

I bought a bluetooth headset and Im trying to connect it to my ubuntu computer, the problem is, first time I tried it showed my device under Device Search but when I selected the device and then clicked next it said failed to connect and now it doesn't even show the device anymore, I have Ubuntu 15.04, the headset works fine with my phone.

These are some outputs:

```
victor@victor-G46VW:~$ pactl list short | grep -i bluetooth
7   module-bluetooth-policy     
8   module-bluetooth-discover   

victor@victor-G46VW:~$ uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
Linux victor-G46VW 3.19.0-47-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 14:02:48 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2123]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:3404 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    4.591161] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    4.591176] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.591181] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.591184] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.591191] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.643538] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A0-13d3-3404.hcd failed with error -2
[    4.643543] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM20702A0-13d3-3404.hcd not found
[    6.673533] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.673536] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.673541] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.681066] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.681073] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.681078] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    0.246266] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.615916] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x460f02)
[    4.643538] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A0-13d3-3404.hcd failed with error -2
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Comment: It won't show the device in device search after pairing, it should show in Bluetooth settings.  Please edit question to include result from terminal for `pactl list short | grep -i bluetooth` thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem reading some other posts, I will post it here so other people having the same problem can solve it, you just have to execute these commands:

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2259248/BCM20702A0-13d3-3404.hcd
sudo cp BCM20702A0-13d3-3404.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```